# Flutter - SliverChildList Text overflow

Tags: flutter, flutter-sliver

I'm trying to get my app polished and noticed an issue with the `SliverChildList` I'm using. When the Text inside is too long to be displayed I get an expection thrown.

How am I able to correctly wrap the Text (not cut)

As in my example most of the entries work just fine. For the elements that overflow I'd like to break the text to the next line and adapt the list element height.

Something simular to:

```
{       } Colombian White-Faced Capuchin
{ image } Monkey
{       } Cebus capucinus
```

I tried adding `overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis` to the text element but it doesn't appear to work the way I'd like it to.

**Code:**

```
SliverList(
  delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
    [
      for (var animal in response)
        GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              print('(DEBUG) Pressed on ${animal['id']} (${animal['name']})');
            },
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                  child: Image.network(
                    animal['image_url'],
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    width: 75,
                    height: 50,
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 10, 20, 10),
                  child: Container(
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(animal['name'].toString(),
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 16,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
                        if (animal['latin_name'] != null)
                          Text(animal['latin_name'].toString(),
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontStyle: FontStyle.italic)),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )),
    ],
  ),
)
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your `Text` widget in a `Flexible` or `Expanded` widget.

Comment: unfortunately wrapping the text in either won't work for me. I wrapped just the bold animal name in these to try and and this was the result: https://imgur.com/a/zqtC6Ei

Comment: Maybe attempt to wrap the 'Padding' widget inside an Expanded then. I think that should work :)